# MySQL updating and converting timezone

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database containing times (ex: 2013-07-10 23:25:36)

They're all in Mountain Standard Time (Calgary) and I need to convert them to UTC.

I've tried to use the following statement to do so, and it resets them all to

0000-00-00 00:00:00

```
UPDATE assets_time SET time=convert_tz(time, 'MST', 'UTC')
```

I would appreciate any advice, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time-zone-support.html) article:

The value can be given as a named time zone, such as 'Europe/Helsinki', 'US/Eastern', or 'MET'. Named time zones can be used only if the time zone information tables in the mysql database have been created and populated.

So this might be your problem. Also have you tried imputing numbers instead? Like this for example:

mysql>UPDATE assets_time SET time=CONVERT_TZ(time,'-07:00','+00:00');

Comment: As it turns out, this didn't work on the production database, but did in the development one...

Comment: You mean you need another solution?

Comment: which goes by `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root mysql`

Answer (score 0):

You must use the standardize format:

```
UPDATE assets_time SET time=convert_tz(time, 'US/Mountain', 'UTC')
```

Comment: Tried it. Completely zero-ed out my entries.

Comment: Have you populate your timezone tables in mysql database ? (http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/timezones.html)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -7 HOUR);

General syntax

SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL  HOUR);

http://www.worldtimebuddy.com/utc-to-pst-converter
since you need for MST it is "-7"